# Bootstrap causes bullets to disappear from unordered lists

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists

I have the same code in a fiddle with bootstrap enabled and in a clean non-bootstrap fiddle.

Why does one have list bullet points and the other does not?

How would I make the bullets show on the unordered list for the Bootstrap fiddle?

---

Here is the code:

```
<ul>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item2</li>
    <li>List Item3</li>
</ul>
```

Here are the two fiddles:

[Bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/dLsgtfzz/2/)

[Non-Bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/kzum16fL/1/)

EDIT:
The problem persists when I have an html file with bootstrap as such.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul><li>List Element</li><ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks like jsfiddle's `normalize.css` is interfering with bootstrap's list styling; this is not a bootstrap issue but a jsfiddle issue afaict

Comment: It also happens in my browser when I create html files. One with bootstrap and one without bootstrap.

Comment: @lexicon see my answer and look closely to the fiddles.

Comment: @dippas I commented on your answer. Check my edit.

Comment: I just stuck `ol, ul { list-style: square inside;}` into the CSS tab, and I got square bullets. That overrides the `ol, li {list-style: none;}` that comes from normalize.css.

Comment: @PaulTomblin as I said it is the normalize,css. but even not using the normalize.css (as OP mentioned) looking into OP code the `ul` isn't be closing properly as I stated in my updated answer

Comment: use Code Inspector and check whether Bootstrap CSS is overriding the bullets or something else.

Answer (score 3):

It is the `normalize.css` that resets the `list-style` to `none` in `ul`

[image: SS]

You have it checked in your bootstrap fiddle, but not in your normal fiddle.

- Check [Fiddle Bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/dLsgtfzz/3/) without `normalize.css` selected
- Check [Normal Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzum16fL/2/) with `normalize.css` selected

---

> The problem still persists with an html file with bootstrap imported

you are not closing the `ul` properly in your updated code.

see this [external file](http://serpa.eusou.com/SO/bst.html) (to impersonate as better your local file) with your code fixed.

also a stack snippet would work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul>
  <li>List Element</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check my edit. The problem still persists with an html file with bootstrap imported.

Comment: @lexicon  see updated answer, next time pay more attention :)

Comment: @lexicon have you checked this yet?